# Xpath for data-reactid element

Tags: python, xpath, scrapy

I want to scrape http://www.spyfu.com/overview/url?query=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.veldemangroup.com%2Fen finding the text elements under "organic keywords", so the first one would be "warehouse structure".

Working in python using scrapy and the command line tool. Trying:

```
response.xpath("//a[@data-reactid='.0.0.0.0.0.1.0.1.0']")
```

just returns "[]" - why is that, how do I get the correct ("warehouse structure") text?

Answer (score 0):

The site you mention is generated dynamically only once you type in `http://www.veldemangroup.com/en`. You can check by typing `scrapy shell http://www.spyfu.com/overview/url?query=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.veldemangroup.com%2Fen` and then `response.body` that there is plenty of javascript and the selector you try to find (or overall others as well) is not there, so Scrapy cannot find it by itself.

Please try Selenium, this would apply not plain request how scrapy does that, but e.g. Firefox webdriver can read the site the way a browser sees this.